# How do you create java packages using notepad++?

Tags: java, notepad++, package

I am trying to create a java file that will read in xml files but for me to do this i need to use a DOM Parser which involves creating a package and declaring it and i was just wondering how do you do that

Comment: Use an IDE like eclipse instead of notepad

Comment: Please, read the [Java Docs on Packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/) to get a better understanding of what packages are.

Comment: Do you want to `import` the `DOM Parser` package you can do that like this(at the top of your class underneath the package declaration for your class): `import whatever.whatever.whatever.DOMParser.*;`

Comment: @Jens, IDE will help him, but here he must understand what are `packages in java`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko But that are the basics of java.

Answer (score 4):

Packages in Java classes reflect the folder structure of your project. For example, if your project is located in the `project` folder, and the structure of your project is:

```
project\
project\mypackage\
project\mypackage\MyClass.java
```

then the MyClass.java file should contain the corresponding package declaration:

```
package mypackage;

public class MyClass {
```

You should also read a tutorial on packages to better understand how they work: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html

Answer (score 0):

A package is declared as the first non-comment line in your Java source file:

```
package an.example.pkg;

public class Foo {
  // code here
}
```

Will declare a class named `Foo` in a package called `an.example.pkg`.

Of course, the package is associated with a folder on your file system, so your `.java` file would actually need to be located in a directory called `<some directory>/an/example/pkg` in your file system (where `<some directory>` is a directory that is in your Java classpath).

The package tells Java where to search to find your classes, i.e. in which folders relative to your classpath to look.